# Android-SD card files updated programmatically are not updated in windows explorer

Tags: android, media

My application does file operations on the SD card (delete or update file). But when I connect the device to Windows 7 through USB, I do not see any changes. However I can confirm files where updated or deleted with adb shell.

I use an ASUS eee Pad with Android 3.0.

It seems devices running Android 3.0 have a different way to provide access to the file system (MTP instead of USB Mass Storage). I also read about how we can use MediaScannerConnection.scanFile to refresh the content of Windows File Explorer when adding a new file.

But how to trigger a refresh when files are deleted or updated?

I tried MediaScannerConnection.scanFile on the deleted file but it only creates an entry with size 0. MediaScannerConnection.scanFile on the whole folder does not work either.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This triggers the refresh but only works on Android < 4.4:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```